# Debug "go get" with dlv

Tags: go, delve

I want to debug `go get` in module-aware mode with `dlv`. Say I have a go module at `/some/dir/mymod`. To use go get in module-aware mode I would have to do the following

```
$ cd /some/dir/mymod
$ go get
```

But if I want to debug the go command itself with `dlv` I would have to do the following

```
$ cd /usr/local/go/src/cmd/go
$ dlv debug -- get [some args here]
```

As you see in order to use `dlv` I need to be in the module that I want to debug, but in order to use `go get` I need to be in the module that I want to update. So the question is: how can I debug `go get` for a particular module with `dlv`?

Comment: What is the end goal here? Is the go binary behaving unexpectedly? This sounds like an [X Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well indeed I had a problem with `go get` and I attempted to debug it but I didn't know how. I solved it and now I honestly have this question...

Comment: I am all for doing things just because you can. These are the questions that teach the most. I'll try my hand at it and get you an answer if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_debug.md, `dlv debug` causes Delve to “Compile and begin debugging main package in current directory, **or the package specified**” (emphasis mine).

So you should be able to do:

```
cd /some/dir/mymod
dlv debug cmd/go -- get …
```

or perhaps

```
cd /some/dir/mymod
dlv debug $(go env GOROOT)/src/cmd/go -- get …
```

Comment: That said, when I need to debug the `go` command (which is pretty often, because that's my day job ), I usually do so by reading the relevant code and injecting calls to `println` and/or `debug.PrintStack`, rather than running the `go` command under a debugger.

Comment: Thanks it works!. I usually prefer your debugging approach when I'm already familiar with the code, but an actual debugger is quite useful when the code is totally new to me ;)